# Mostrar la ruta de una imagen dentro de un modal según desde dónde se haga click

Tags: jquery, html5, bootstrap

Tengo una estructura html bastante sencilla, 3 párrafos con una imagen distinta en cada uno. A su vez los párrafos tienen un enlace a un modal de `bootstrap` :

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <p id="parrafo1">
          <img src="img/img1" alt="">
          <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Abrir modal</a>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <p id="parrafo2">
          <img src="img/img2" alt="">
          <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Abrir modal</a>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <p id="parrafo3">
          <img src="img/img3" alt="">
          <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Abrir modal</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <p>
            Ruta de la imagen del párrafo desde el que se ha hecho click en el modal: 
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

En el modal me gustaría visualizar la ruta de la imagen que esté en el interior del párrafo desde el que se ha hecho click. ¿Cual sería la forma más óptima de hacerlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay muchas formas de hacerlo, te muestro mi versión rápida jQuery, la cual consiste en:

- Trabajar con el evento click del `<a>`
- Obtener el valor del atributo src del elemento anterior `<img>`
- Obtener el data-target del elemento `<a>` para ubicarlo en el mismo modal que se está mostrando y completar el selector con la clase o etiquetas correspondientes a donde quieras ubicar la ruta
- Reemplazar el html

Aquí el código:

```js
$('a[data-toggle=modal]').click(function(){
  var img_path = $(this).prev('img').attr('src');

  $($(this).data('target')+' .modal-header p').html(img_path);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <p id="parrafo1">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports" alt="">
          <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Abrir modal</a>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <p id="parrafo2">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/city" alt="">
          <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Abrir modal</a>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <p id="parrafo3">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/transport" alt="">
          <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Abrir modal</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <p>
            Ruta de la imagen del párrafo desde el que se ha hecho click en el modal: 
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```